# ArrayList and public classes

Tags: java, arraylist

I'm a first year university student and I need some help. Firstly, the code is based on what I've been taught in during lectures. As you can see, I have created a public class Question1, which takes the properties of an array list.

The main issue I'm having is that as you can see I have wrote the .add function, allowing me to add to the arraylist. But I'm presuming, how it is all setup it means that I can't use the basic arraylist functions. The main 2 I need to add is .remove, so I can remove from the arraylist based on an index. The other being .get.

Is there an easy way to make it default the ArrayList functions or can someone help me create them like I've done with my `.add`.

Class code:

```
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class Question1 {

    private ArrayList<Question1Entry> entries;

    public Question1() {
        entries = new ArrayList<Question1Entry>();
    }

    public void add( String name, String studentNumber, String courseName, String courseID, String houseNumber, String streetName, String town, String postcode ) {
        entries.add(new Question1Entry(name, studentNumber, courseName, courseID, houseNumber, streetName, town, postcode ));
    }


    //PhoneBook.java given code
    public String toString( ) {
        StringBuffer temp = new StringBuffer();
        for (int i = 0; i < entries.size(); ++i) {
            temp.append( entries.get(i).toString() + "\n" );
        }
        return temp.toString();
    }    
}
```

Code found in the test document:

```
Question1 sd = new Question1();
```

(Loosened to the only relevant part)

Comment: `entries.add()` and `sd.add()` are completely separate methods

Comment: Well, we don't know what your teacher has asked you to do, and you also haven't really made it clear what help you need.  Using an extra class like this to wrap up the functionality of an ArrayList is a little unusual though - it would be more common just to use an ArrayList directly.  No idea whether that's within the scope of your assignment though.

Comment: @DawoodibnKareem - This seems like the first step leading to a more complex class where wrapping an ArrayList would be a perfectly sensible thing to do.

Comment: What is the objective of the task?

Comment: Where exactly are you stuck implementing get or remove methods?

Comment: @TedHopp I agree completely.  But OP needs to state his/her question clearly, otherwise he/she is unlikely to get a good answer from anyone who doesn't have psychic powers.  Of course, now I see that one person has successfully guessed what the question was about.  The OP was lucky this time, but in future, they need to make things clearer in their questions.

Comment: I'm glad that your question has been answered, but in the future, please strive to ask a cleaner more easily understood question. Please have a look at the [ask] as it can help you achieve this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do the same you've done for your add method with remove and get if you know the index:

```
public void removeQuestion(int index){
  entries.remove(index);
}

public Question1Entry getQuestion(int index){
  return entries.get(index);
}
```

if you don't know the index you can loop through your entries `ArrayList` comparing whatever info you have to the Objects of your list that method could look something like this for get:

```
public Question1Entry getQuestion(your infos){
  for(Question1Entry q : entries){
    //compare it
    if(correct){
      return q;
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you I didn't expect the replies to be so quickly!  You're the only person that seems to understand my issue.  I just didn't know if there was an easier way then making it all manual :)